# Selecting and highlighting in a column using row numbers from different cells

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Help:  I have two cells in the same column in Excel  marked with an `x` (for convenience).  I want to use the row numbers of these cells to highlight and select a range in another column between these 2 cells so that I can copy them and paste them as I please.  Please tell me how to do it a macro.  Appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us what you've come up with so far?

Answer (score 0):

1. Set ActiveCell to be the first cell of the desired column.
2. Use either For or Do..While loop: If the ActiveCell.Value isn't 'x' then set ActiveCell.Value to be the cell under it and continue the loop. If it is 'x' then: On the first occurance of the 'x' store the row index (i.e. ActiveCell.Row), on the second occurance break the loop. The row index of the second occurance will be in the ActiveCell.Row.
3. Select cells between the two occurances. (It's easy to learn with macro recorder)

Tips:

- You can do and learn a lot with macro recorder.
- There are many free VBA tutorials on Youtube [Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t1vdt0FddsE) and Google [Example1](http://www.homeandlearn.org/excel_vba_for_loops.html) [Example2](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/create-a-macro.html)